# How to do a boxplot in R with a missing grouping level

Tags: r, boxplot

I have data over 15 consecutive months, but there are no observations for month 12.

I have "month" coded in the `data.frame` as an integer from 1 to 15. There are no occurrences of 12.

`boxplot (data$y ~ data$month)` seems to convert month to a factor, with 14 levels, so I don't see a gap where month 12 data would be, if there were any.

How can I get boxplot to leave a gap at 12?  I'd like to overlay a regression line, but it won't be right without the gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that `boxplot()` converts your months to a factor.

Tell R explicitly that 12 would be a valid factor level, and you are good to go:

```
data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(200),month=sample(c(1:11,13:15),200,replace=TRUE))
with(data,boxplot(y~factor(month,levels=1:15)))
```

[image: boxplots]