# How to do a boxplot in R with a missing grouping level and two factors

Tags: boxplot, missing-data, factors, group

8 years and eight months ago, the first part of my question was answered perfectly for a boxplot with a missing grouping level by Stephan Kolassa when one level (12) was missing:

[How to do a boxplot in R with a missing grouping level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788336/how-to-do-a-boxplot-in-r-with-a-missing-grouping-level)

```
data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(200),month=sample(c(1:11,13:15),200,replace=TRUE))
with(data,boxplot(y~factor(month,levels=1:15)))
```

But how should I create a dataframe not just for month as a factor but combined with a two-level factor, say age (young vs old)?

I have tried several possibilities without success.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some data including a second factor (note that I already define the original data as `ordered` factors):

```
nn <- 1000
set.seed(1)  # for replicability
data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(nn),
    month=ordered(sample(c(1:11,13:15),nn,replace=TRUE),levels=1:15),
    age=ordered(sample(c("young","old"),nn,replace=TRUE),levels=c("young","old")))
colors <- structure(c("green","red"),.Names=levels(data$age))
```

In principle, R deals quite gracefully with *interactions* of factors (as for statistical models, and specified in the same way), so the following "works":

```
with(data,boxplot(y~age*month))
```

Unfortunately, it looks very bad. While we do have two missing boxplots, everything else is jumbled together, and the annotations on the horizontal axis are hard to understand. (Also, if we feed in the colors, the order comes out all wrong.)

The key is to call `boxplot()` *without plotting* and store the results, which contain all the information we need to plot the boxplot. Afterwards, we plot the boxplots in a nicer and more informative way.

Calculate all the information and store them without plotting:

```
foo <- with(data,boxplot(y~age*month, plot=FALSE))
```

Take a look at `foo` and see how it contains all the information. Specifically, note that `foo$names` tells us that the data is ordered such that we first have the two entries for month 1, then two for month 2 etc. (rather than first having 15 entries for `young`, followed by 15 for `old`, which we would get by specifying `month*age` rather than `age*month`, in which case we would need to adapt the subsequent script accordingly).

Here is a little magic to extract the `age` category for each entry, using `strsplit` on `foo$names`:

```
(age_category <- sapply(strsplit(foo$names,".",fixed=TRUE),"[",1))
```

Now, let's plot this. First, we will group the two boxplots for the two `age` categories in each month together and leave some space between the months. For this, we specify where we want to plot:

```
n_months <- max(as.numeric(as.character(data$month)))
(xx <- as.vector(rbind(3*(0:(n_months-1))+1, 3*(0:(n_months-1))+2)))
```

Now we plot, using the `bxp()` function, feeding the `xx` vector into the `at` parameter, and using our named (!) vector of colors above for the `boxfill` parameter. We suppress the horizontal axis.

```
bxp(foo, at=xx, boxfill=colors[age_category], las=1, xlab="Month", xaxt="n")
```

Note how the two boxplots for `month=12` are missing. It should also work if some particular combination between `month` and `age` has no data. Add the horizontal axis:

```
axis(1,at=3*(1:n_months)-1.5,labels=1:n_months)
```

Finally, add a legend. Be careful not to cover any data points (the misleadingly so-called "outliers"), potentially add some vertical space using `ylim` in `bxp()`:

```
legend("top", fill=colors, legend=names(colors))
```

[image: boxplots]

Alternatively, it looks like [`ggplot2` has some built-in support for grouped boxplots](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+grouped+boxplot).

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your elaborate response. This is perfect!

Comment: Hi Stephan, I have tried to apply your codes to a sample of my own data. Unfortunately, it didn't work the way I expected. SO doesn't allow to upoad data, but perhaps the error message is helpfull already.

Comment: I have ordered my data the following way:

Comment: ```
df3$x <- factor(df3$x, levels = c(1976, 1979:1981,1983), ordered = TRUE)
df3$age <- factor(df3$age,levels=c("young", "old"), ordered = TRUE)
colors <- structure(c("green","red"),.Names=levels(df3$age))
```

Comment: `
bxp(foo, at=xx, boxfill=colors[age_category], las=1, xlab="Year", xaxt="n", add = TRUE)
`
_Error in bxp(foo, at = xx, boxfill = colors[age_category], las = 1, xlab = "Year",  : 
  'at' must have same length as 'z$n', i.e. 10_

Comment: Hi Frans, apologies, I was quite busy the last couple of days. It may already be helpful to do `df3$x <- factor(df3$x, levels = c(1976:1983), ordered = TRUE)` (explicitly adding the missing years as possible factor levels) and `xx <- levels(df3$x)`. If that does not work, you should be able to edit your own post and include the output of `dput(df3)` right before you call `boxplot()`, which would make it easier to help you. If you decide to edit your post with this data, then please ping me in the comments, and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very grateful that you want to pay attention to this issue. I have followed your suggestions without the desired outcome, however.
I have a data file with three gaps, 1977, 1978, and 1982, ranging from 1977:1983, the data file contains 350 observations. This is my code:

```
df3 <- get(load("example.Rdata"))
df3$x <- factor(df3$x, levels = c(1976:1983), ordered = TRUE)
xx <- levels(df3$x)
df3$age <- factor(df3$age,levels=c("young", "old"), ordered = TRUE)
colors <- structure(c("green","red"),.Names=levels(df3$age))
with(df3,boxplot(y~x*age))
foo <- with(df3,boxplot(y~x*age, plot=FALSE))
(age_category <- sapply(strsplit(foo$names,".",fixed=TRUE),"[",1))
options(max.print = 1500000)
n_x <- max(as.numeric(as.character(df3$x)))
(xx <- as.vector(rbind(3*(0:(n_x-1))+1, 3*(0:(n_x-1))+2)))
head(xx)

dput(df3)
structure(list(y = c(35L, 43L, 44L, 23L, 53L, 24L, 36L, 52L, 
49L, 49L, 49L, 43L, 33L, 39L, 44L, 34L, 49L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 50L, 
37L, 30L, 43L, 45L, 43L, 39L, 35L, 20L, 28L, 53L, 52L, 44L, 55L, 
52L, 43L, 45L, 30L, 55L, 52L, 43L, 55L, 44L, 42L, 32L, 46L, 18L, 
33L, 45L, 46L, 43L, 56L, 56L, 36L, 32L, 46L, 32L, 49L, 36L, 40L, 
46L, 38L, 43L, 46L, 45L, 46L, 34L, 45L, 38L, 44L, 29L, 50L, 43L, 
55L, 43L, 41L, 44L, 25L, 45L, 42L, 30L, 45L, 32L, 42L, 49L, 33L, 
41L, 27L, 57L, 49L, 37L, 48L, 45L, 44L, 24L, 37L, 39L, 35L, 42L, 
60L, 40L, 52L, 55L, 48L, 37L, 38L, 54L, 36L, 50L, 42L, 39L, 34L, 
34L, 35L, 26L, 21L, 41L, 21L, 43L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 38L, 
48L, 34L, 46L, 59L, 44L, 51L, 38L, 37L, 43L, 45L, 52L, 53L, 42L, 
54L, 45L, 55L, 37L, 44L, 55L, 33L, 50L, 39L, 44L, 36L, 43L, 42L, 
26L, 40L, 36L, 30L, 29L, 46L, 41L, 28L, 44L, 48L, 30L, 40L, 39L, 
49L, 37L, 54L, 42L, 38L, 36L, 46L, 44L, 27L, 49L, 49L, 30L, 40L, 
21L, 51L, 58L, 53L, 40L, 37L, 56L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 57L, 51L, 41L, 
30L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 31L, 28L, 34L, 49L, 42L, 35L, 42L, 42L, 52L, 
27L, 47L, 47L, 44L, 24L, 38L, 56L, 38L, 48L, 34L, 27L, 44L, 31L, 
48L, 42L, 48L, 48L, 53L, 34L, 53L, 28L, 29L, 37L, 36L, 58L, 20L, 
51L, 31L, 29L, 47L, 36L, 42L, 37L, 42L, 45L, 55L, 32L, 48L, 39L, 
39L, 45L, 24L, 26L, 46L, 54L, 29L, 47L, 37L, 38L, 49L, 32L, 38L, 
46L, 47L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 52L, 55L, 41L, 44L, 57L, 44L, 58L, 50L, 
30L, 27L, 22L, 42L, 50L, 35L, 28L, 46L, 53L, 51L, 42L, 49L, 42L, 
58L, 52L, 39L, 51L, 50L, 52L, 43L, 42L, 38L, 43L, 46L, 38L, 36L, 
47L, 26L, 19L, 37L, 45L, 49L, 48L, 28L, 35L, 57L, 45L, 34L, 40L, 
32L, 28L, 47L, 25L, 54L, 44L, 37L, 55L, 56L, 26L, 49L, 39L, 45L, 
26L, 47L, 41L, 58L, 45L, 44L, 47L, 31L, 39L, 46L, 35L, 46L, 29L, 
40L, 40L, 48L, 19L, 39L, 35L, 30L, 38L, 42L, 46L, 48L, 25L, 28L, 
41L, 24L, 28L, 48L), x = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 
8L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 
4L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("1976", "1977", "1978", 
"1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), age = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("young", "old"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -350L), class = "data.frame")`

bxp(foo, at=xx, boxfill=colors[age_category], las=1, xlab="Year", xaxt="n", add = TRUE)
```

Error in bxp(foo, at = xx, boxfill = colors[age_category], las = 1, xlab = "Year",  :
'at' must have same length as 'z$n', i.e. 16

```
axis(1,at=3*(1:n_x)-1.5,labels=1:n_x)
legend("top", fill=colors, legend=names(colors))
with(df3,boxplot(y~factor(x,levels=1976:1983)* age_category))
```

I hope this info is helpful.